# Joomla: ZOOfilter module layout is empty?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I'm using Joomla 3.2.3 and for commerce purpose, I've installed the ZOO package and all of its apps.

Now, I've a page displaying Items of a Category. I needed a filter in this page and thus installed ZOOfilter Module for it.

I've filled all the relevant fields of that module but I'm getting this message on the categories page:

> ZOOfilter Module layout is empty. Check documentation, you probably missed "Choose the filters" step.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Fathir Ali! What did you found  in the documentation? Did you found this option of "Choose the filters"? Have you tried to reinstall again the program?

Comment: Thank you very much for Welcoming me..
Sorry for late reply, I was searching for more and trying to find the solution
No, there wasn't any option "Choose the filters"
I've reinstalled it but similar

Comment: Found the solution myself...

Comment: The ZOO Component area contains Settings tab
->Product Catalog
->Name "Product"
->Edit Element

Answer (score 0):

To close the question the solution as pointed in the comments is to go to Settings tab ->Product Catalog ->Name "Product" ->Edit Element And modified the option to choose the filters.